# Formula to convert y-value to pre-defined range?

Tags: actionscript-3, formulas

I have a graph that goes from a min value of 30 to a max value of 240 but my actual Y value is a range of 216-435. I'm trying to make a draggable line correspond to the values on my graph (30-240) and could use help with the formula.

This screencast will help a lot. http://screencast.com/t/PpVXNAtZD9Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use percentages:

```
// Graph Range
var gMax:Number = 240;
var gMin:Number = 30;

// Y Range
var yMax:Number = 435;
var yMin:Number = 216;

var percent:Number = (actualY - yMin) / (yMax - yMin);
var corresponding:Number = percent * (gMax - gMin) + gMin;
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Had to switch my gMax & gMin because my graph is kind of backwards, but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :D  Also, as a heads up, there's a [Math Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) full of people way smarter than myself who'll answer the really tough math-based questions.